# Comparing sysdate and the current date for rescheduling

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to extract date from my database in MS Access. I want to compare this date for long till it sysdate is near it. I have written something like this -

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement p =c.prepareStatement("select Message,SendDate from mesaages12 where SendDate between sysdate - 0.25 and sysdate + 0.25");
        r1 = p.executeQuery();
        // another class object called
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it does not seem to be working. Plus i am having the problem, if it is null , it throws an exception.

Anyone having a better option ... please comment.

My schema of table -

```
Message GroupName SendDate
text    text      Date/Time
```

Date is in format 12-Jul-14 11:00:47 AM

Answer (score 0):

For a query against an Access database you need to use `Now()` instead of `sysdate`. (`sysdate` is an Oracle function.)

So the query would be

```sql
SELECT Message, SendDate FROM mesaages12 
WHERE SendDate BETWEEN Now() - 0.25 AND Now() + 0.25
```

and it would return rows where [SendDate] is within a 12 hour window centered on the current local system time.

To handle the case where there are no matching rows you could do something like this

```java
p = c.prepareStatement("SELECT Message, SendDate FROM mesaages12 WHERE SendDate BETWEEN Now() - 0.25 AND Now() + 0.25");
ResultSet r1 = p.executeQuery();
if (r1.next()) {
    while (true) {
        // do something with the current row of the ResultSet
        //   for demonstration purposes, we'll just print the [Message] text
        System.out.println(r1.getString(1));
        if (!r1.next()) break;
    }
}
else {
    // code to handle the case where no rows are returned
    System.out.println("The query did not return any rows.");
}
```